# select maximum value of common column for multiple data set

Tags: sql, sas

I have a daily schedule process flow which refreshes a bunch of tables within the same library. At the end of the process flow, all tables should have the same up to date records. And I want to double check this via checking the maximum value of `date`.

But problem is, how can I quickly extract all max value of date among these tables and then compare them?

```
proc sql;
select max(date) from lib.table1;
select max(date) from lib.table2;
select max(date) from lib.table3;
...
quit;
```

Comment: Is the daily process flow running all the time, or is there downtime?  How many tables are being written?

Comment: There's downtime for the process flow. 10-20 tables.

Comment: Do you tables have any naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view that appends all the tables with the date variable and select the max date from the variable. If your tables don't have the same structure you can modify the set statement to keep only the date variable. You may want to anyways to speed up the process.

```
data max_date/view=max_date;
   set table: indsname=source;
   dset=source;
   keep date dset;
run;

proc sql;
  create table maximum_date as
  select max(date) as Latest_Date 
  from max_date
  group by dset;
 quit;
```

Comment: thanks for the 'indsname' option. But the tables' naming doesn't have any pattern.

Comment: If you can't explicitly list them you can probably query a list from dictionary.table

Answer (score 0):

In plain SQL it would look like

```
select 'table1' table_name, max(date) max from lib.table1
union all
select 'table2' table_name, max(date) max from lib.table2
union all
select 'table3' table_name, max(date) max from lib.table3
```

Other options are stored procedures, in-line views and probably more.

Answer (score 0):

If they're all huge datasets (which I'm guessing they are) then you might be better off dropping a retain of the maximum date in the last processing datastep of each dataset you have to compare against - and then saving these to macro variables:

```
data table1(drop=maxdate) ;
  retain maxdate ;
  set _table1 end=eof ;
  *** other code here ;

  if date>maxdate then maxdate=date ;
  if eof then call symput('table1mdt',maxdate) ;
run ;
```

You can then write these out to a report such as ;

```
data _null_ ;
  put "Table1 max date= &table1mdt" ;
  put "Table2 max date= &table2mdt" ;
run ;
```

Comment: Ooops, actullay I'm worry about the repetitive step to extract max values. Is there any way to extra values from multiple tables in one or two data steps?

Comment: The first step above would just be 'piggy backing' the `maxdate` variable in whatever final datastep you are doing for each dataset so there is virtually no no extra workload - it just puts your max date for each datastep to a macro variable to compare with the final `data _null_`. Otherwise which repetitive step are you referring to?

Comment: @Bendy I think they're referring to macro-ising the code so it will run for 20 tables...